# How to configure urls.py in django to redirect to another file's urls?

Tags: python, django

I'm following a django tutorial that is a little outdated and in the urls.py file of the first app's directory we need to configure where to direct django to for any url starting with 'notes/'.
There are two separate 'apps' inside the project. I'm in the first one, not notes.

This is the code currently. I added `include` to import statement:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(url(r’^notes/‘, include('notes.urls'))),
]
```

Inside the urlpatterns object, on the first line, `path('admin/', admin.site.urls)`, comes predefined, but I need to add a redirect such that django goes to a different app, called 'notes' and searches there for its entry point, since all of the urls will begin with *‘notes/’*.

The tutorial says to use a regular expression and uses this code:

```
url(r’^notes/‘, include(notes.urls))
```

so that any url that starts with 'notes/' should be redirected to this other file `notes.urls`.

However the predefined ones that currently come out of the box with a django project start with `path`.
I enclosed my notes/n redirect line in path, but not sure if this is correct. Should I instead directly write:

```
url(r’^notes/‘, include(notes.urls))
```

Also, do I need to delete the first line provided?

```
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

The tutorial has:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',   
 url(r’^notes/‘, include(notes.urls)),
)
```

and no admin urls line. It's from 2014 I believe.

Comment: "Should I instead directly write:" did you try writing it?

Comment: Yes, and it has a syntax error using the version as per above. I am a beginner here and don't know how it check if it's correct. If you can help, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do:

```
path('notes/', include('notes.urls'))
```